# Subclassing String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, methods, instance

I have a string method `String.prototype.splitName()` that splits an author's name (a string) in first name(s) and a last name. The statement  `var name = authorName.splitname();` returns an object literal `name` with `name.first = "..."` and `name.last = "..."` (properties of `name` have string values).

Recently I was told that it is unwise to have `splitName()` as a method of the **public** String() class, but that I should make a **private** subclass  of  String  and extend the subclass (instead of the public class) with my function.  My question is: how do I perform subclassing for strings so that after I assign `authorName` to the new subclass `name = authorName.splitname();` is still a valid statement? And how would I assign `authorName` to the new private subclass of String?

Comment: Don't do that. Either create your own objects or use a function. Read [Maintainable JavaScript: Don’t modify objects you don’t own](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/)/

Comment: You can take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/NV/282770).

Comment: This looks horrible. This "subclass" of String is mutable, and its `length` is not even guaranteed to be equal to its length.

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by https://gist.github.com/NV/282770 I answer my own question. In the
ECMAScript-5 code below I define an object class "StringClone". By (1) the class
inherits all properties from the native class "String". An instance of
"StringClone" is an object to which the methods of "String" cannot be applied
without a trick. When a string method is applied, JavaScript invokes the methods
"toString()" and/or "valueOf()". By overriding these methods in (2), the
instance of class "StringClone" is made to behave like a string. Finally, the
property "length" of an instance becomes read-only, which is why (3) is
introduced.

```
// Define class StringClone
function StringClone(s) {
    this.value = s || '';
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'length', {get:
                function () { return this.value.length; }});    //(3)
};
StringClone.prototype = Object.create(String.prototype);        //(1)
StringClone.prototype.toString = StringClone.prototype.valueOf
                               = function(){return this.value}; //(2)

// Example, create instance author:
var author = new StringClone('John Doe');  
author.length;           // 8
author.toUpperCase();    // JOHN DOE

// Extend class with a trivial method
StringClone.prototype.splitName = function(){
     var name = {first: this.substr(0,4), last: this.substr(4) };
     return name;
}

author.splitName().first; // John
author.splitName().last;  // Doe
```

Comment: very nice dude, thumbs up