# How does JavaScript define a new string type?

Tags: javascript

First, I define a default string.

```
var string = new String();
```

But I wanted to have a more powerful string, so I added some methods to the prototype of string.

```
String.prototype.md5sck
```

That's good, but I hope he's a new type.

```
var string2 = new String2();
string2.prototype.substring();//Method with inherit default string
string2.prototype.md5sck();//Have additional methods
string.prototype.md5sck();//null The system default string method will not be affected.
```

And I have to make sure my method can't be modified by others

```
var string2 = new string2();
string2.prototype.md5sck = ???; // After new(), I hope this behavior will be prohibited
```

Comment: What is your question? 

Comment: You can just define a Class like `class String2`. ?

Comment: Is TypeScript what you are looking for?

Comment: You have two questions here. For the first one, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151450/subclassing-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var string = new String();
String.prototype.md5sck = () => { console.log("md5 check") };

class String2 extends String {
   // define here
}

var string2 = new String2();

string2.md5sck()
```

Comment: It's so simple, I see